# How to interact with Openmodelica embedded opc-ua server

Tags: opc-ua, openmodelica

I have built and started an OPC UA embedded Openmodelica server with the BouncingBall model like so:

```
$ omc +s path/to/model
$ ./BouncingBall -embeddedServer=opc-ua -rt=1
```

Now I'm trying to interact with it using an OPCUA client. However, I don't understand how I'm supposed to interact with the server properly. As far as I know this is undocumented.

1. The most promising approach seems to be to set `enableStopTime` to `false` and `run` to `true`. Then the simulation seems to run indefinitely and the values seem to make sense. It seems I'm only able to extract the values in real time however. While running, when I set `run` to `false` it seems that the server enters an erroneous state and it refuses to give any values back.
2. If I restart the executable and instead set `step` to `true` nothing seems to change and after trying to set `step` to `true` a second time the server becomes unresponsive. The `-rt=1` option doesn't seem to matter. Seems like it enters the same state as above (1).
3. (After restart) If I leave `enableStopTime` to be `true` and set `run` to `true` the simulation runs to stop and then the server quits with message `The simulation finished successfully`. Maybe this is intended. Kind of seems odd. Would make sense to be able to restart the simulation or trigger it with new options.

**What I would hope to be able to do**: Start and stop simulation as well as rewind to a certain point to check the value at that point. It seems to me that the API "affords" this functionality and it could probably be provided by hackingly wrapping the executable and API. Are the above bugs or intended? What is the intended way to interact with an OPC UA server in these cases?

The OpenModelica compiler version is 1.16.0~1-g84b4a71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the [latest nightly build](https://build.openmodelica.org/omc/builds/windows/nightly-builds/64bit/)
It includes the following [commit](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/commit/990310b9f54993575b5b3c88eb8045a9b962cc3d).

That might solve it. I believe things worked without subscriptions before, since I could never reproduce this without them.

(By the way, do people go on our git commit feed and try to reproduce bugs fixed in the last 24 hours; we quite often get questions that were just recently fixed)

Comment: I'm running on linux and could not find recent build for that so I built from master. Master seems much more stable but I still can't rewind to a previous point. Trying to set time doesn't work. So I guess in order to retrieve the historical data points I have to read simulation output from disk?

Comment: Oh, I see that `step` seems to mostly work as a I expect though, with 0,002 increments. Although the first step seems to be ignored.

Comment: It's quite enough for what I wanted to do and no I did not try to reproduce the bug. I wanted to try out openmodelica as a backend for an experiment by coincidence. :)

Comment: There are Linux nightly builds for Debian/Ubuntu/CentOS/Fedora. As for the step, you can modify the step size before starting the simulation. And you're right initialization might be a bit odd. You won't be able to set or go back in time (time is read only).